# Having problems with a local yum repo

Tags: centos-7, yum

I've tried to set up a local repo on a server (alecto) using `reposync`.  This part seems to go OK and the the target directory (/repo) gets populated.

I did this so I could update multiple VMs running CentOS without hammering my Internet connection.

The problem is that when using 'yum update' on the VMs, it fails on most (not all) packages, apparently looking for older versions of that package than is installed in the /repo directory.  For example, it looks to install `zlib-1.2.7-17` when the version in `/repo` is `zlib-1.2.7-18`.  I have no idea where it gets the idea that the -17 version should be used.

There is only one repo defined in the VM's `/etc/yum.repos.d directory - alecto.repo` and that contains:

```
[alecto]
name=Local network repo on Alecto
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.110/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

It's not the FTP setup - some installations work (eg `yum install pigz`) and it's possible that they work because their version number doesn't change very often.

I've run `createrepo` on all the reposync'ed directories and I have cleared out all `yum` caches on the VM.

My question is:  What the heck is going on?  Failing that: where does `yum` get the version numbers of what it thinks it needs to install?

I have been beating my head against a wall for two days now and could really use some help.

Comment: On the VMs you ran `yum clean all`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of Q&A's on access.redhat.com that show the following setup:

For the VMs

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
[RHEL7]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=ftp://<ip_address>/<somedirectory>/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

You'd then run the following:

```
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum repolist
[...]
RHEL7             | 1.5 kB     00:00     
RHEL7/primary     | 920 kB     00:00     
RHEL7                               3285/3285

repo id          repo name       status

RHEL7 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - x86_64     3,285
            repolist: 3,285
```

You can then run on the VMs:

```
$ sudo yum update
```

**NOTE1:** This is the URL but it requires an account to see it - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3187892.

The Q&A also referenced this video on Youtube which anyone can view titled:[Creating a Local Repository and Sharing With Offline Systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAIjTpXwpuI&feature=youtu.be).

**NOTE2:** You do not show your `reposync` method for pulling the repo down, but I suspect that the method you used is the root of your issue. Take a look at the video, it shows how to properly perform a `reposync`.

Comment: I have followed the tutorials and some of it seems to work. The command I use to set up /reo is 'reposync -g -l -d -n -p /repo
createrepo /repo'

Comment: It seems the basic setup works, but I still have the problem of the differing package versions.  Where is the client yum getting a version of the package that doesn't even exist in the /repo directory?

Comment: @cassini232 - it can only get it from 2 places, either a errant repo or a cache. You could try running `yum` with more verbose logging to see where it's getting this package.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I was thrown by the fact that issuing the reposync command used alecto's own yum.repos.d to populate /repo.  Somehow I thought the same would apply to the client - it doesn't, so I can't just specify /repo as the start point on the client.  This means that alecto.repo goes from looking like this

```
[alecto]
name=Local network repo on Alecto
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.110/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

to this

```
[base]
name=Local network repo on Alecto - base
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.110/base/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[epel]
name=Local network repo on Alecto - epel
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.110/epel/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

etc...
```

I still don't understand where the -17 version of zlib came from, but that's something I'll look into when I have more time.